# Use Gravity Forms and a Shopping Cart for output to Freshbooks for an Estimate

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, customization, api, plugin-gravity-forms

I've been asked to develop a website pretty much like (but not the same as):
http://www.yoursingapore.com/

basically we need to allow people to add Wordpress posts (custom post types) into a sort of shopping cart (people won't make any payment); the website won't have any checkout, but the resulting list of items (posts), each one carrying one cost and other details in meta fields and gravity form (http://www.gravityforms.com/) options, should be sent to Freshbooks (http://www.freshbooks.com/) to generate an estimate (or be used for other purposes as well, ie. sent as email, or other services, within our outside Wordpress)

What would you use to combine Gravity Forms with? 
I don't think I can do the job myself unless there's a solution ready (which I doubt), I'd rather hire a developer for my project. Nevertheless, I would like to hear some opinion on what would be the best route to go.

To recap

- we have a website with custom post types
- each custom post type has certain custom fields with prices and details
- users, through gravity forms, should be able to specify further details like dates (ie checkin/checkout) and options (price changes)
- by clicking "add to list" the item is sent to the shopping cart
- when the user has finished, he should be able to review and eventually edit the resulting list
- then send the quotation request, which will be deliered to Freshbooks as an Estimate, including Client contact creation within Freshbooks (using Freshbooks API)
- eventully the same data of the final "cart" form could be used also for other puroposes

thanks for any opinion you will share with me

Answer (score 1):

Why use gravity post if you just want to do post add/insert + post_meta (assume on front-end), we can do it as long as we give a registered user certain capabilities. We can achieved this by creating custom role for user to add to specific custom post type, . For email notification you can use native wp_mail on wp_insert_post function (logged_in)

```
    $orderpost = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, etc.
    'post_type'     => 'item-order' , // Use a custom post type if you want to
);
$the_inserted = wp_insert_post($orderpost);  // Pass  the value of $post to WordPress the insert function
```

after post succeed ($the_inserted = id of 'item-order') we can create function such as add_post_meta, update_post_meta, wp_mail or wp_redirect

Cheers :-)